# Unicode range for Japanese

Tags: unicode

I am trying to separate English and Japanese characters. I need to find Unicode range of all Japanese characters. What is Unicode range of all Japanese characters ?

Comment: Why don't you [look it up on the official Unicode site?](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) - that would be your best reference ...

Comment: Japanese seems to have multiple scripts, so I was not sure to about all scripts Japanese have. Can you tell me something about it.

Comment: What do you intend to do with fullwidth alphabetic? They are both English and Japanese.

Comment: For a starter, define “English characters” and “Japanese characters”. Is “1” English, Japanese, both, or neither? What about “é”? You should decide what you really want to do, and this requires understanding your goal, the application contexts, etc. – things that are outside the scope of SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CJK(Chinese Japanese and Korean), Hiragana and Katakana(include Halfwidth Katakana)

http://www.unicode.org/charts/

Comment: Answers should be self contained. Links should be for context, background material and sources. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Answer (score 58):

As zawhtut mentioned, [this page](http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.unicode.shtml) has a reference for several unicode ranges. To summarize the ranges:

- Japanese-style punctuation ( 3000 - 303f)
- Hiragana ( 3040 - 309f)
- Katakana ( 30a0 - 30ff)
- Full-width roman characters and half-width katakana ( ff00 - ffef)
- CJK unifed ideographs - Common and uncommon kanji ( 4e00 - 9faf)

Comment: That is a nice overview but one has to be careful with the Hiragana range. U+3040, U+3097 and U+3098 are not actually Hiragana characters.

Answer (score 44):

Although this question already has an answer, [this blog post](http://www.localizingjapan.com/blog/2012/01/20/regular-expressions-for-japanese-text/) is probably more complete.

Please visit the site and get their metrics up, but for posterity here's a copy-paste.

> **Hiragana**
>
> Unicode code points regex: `[\x3041-\x3096]`
>
> Unicode block property regex: `\p{Hiragana}`
>
> ぁ あ ぃ い ぅ う ぇ え ぉ お か が き ぎ く ぐ け げ こ ご さ ざ し じ す ず せ ぜ そ ぞ た だ ち ぢ っ
>   つ づ て で と ど な に ぬ ね の は ば ぱ ひ び ぴ ふ ぶ ぷ へ べ ぺ ほ ぼ ぽ ま み む め も ゃ や ゅ ゆ
>   ょ よ ら り る れ ろ ゎ わ ゐ ゑ を ん ゔ ゕ ゖ  ゙ ゚ ゛ ゜ ゝ ゞ ゟ
>
> **Katakana (Full Width)**
>
> Unicode code points regex: `[\x30A0-\x30FF]`
>
> Unicode block property regex: `\p{Katakana}`
>
> ゠ ァ ア ィ イ ゥ ウ ェ エ ォ オ カ ガ キ ギ ク グ ケ ゲ コ ゴ サ ザ シ ジ ス ズ セ ゼ ソ ゾ タ ダ チ ヂ
>   ッ ツ ヅ テ デ ト ド ナ ニ ヌ ネ ノ ハ バ パ ヒ ビ ピ フ ブ プ ヘ ベ ペ ホ ボ ポ マ ミ ム メ モ ャ ヤ ュ
>   ユ ョ ヨ ラ リ ル レ ロ ヮ ワ ヰ ヱ ヲ ン ヴ ヵ ヶ ヷ ヸ ヹ ヺ ・ ー ヽ ヾ ヿ
>
> **Kanji**
>
> Unicode code points regex: `[\x3400-\x4DB5\x4E00-\x9FCB\xF900-\xFA6A]`
>
> Unicode block property regex: `\p{Han}`
>
> 漢字 日本語 文字 言語 言葉 etc. Too many characters to list.
>
> This regular expression will match all the kanji, including those used
>   in Chinese.
>
> **Kanji Radicals**
>
> Unicode code points regex: `[\x2E80-\x2FD5]`
>
> ⺀ ⺁ ⺂ ⺃ ⺄ ⺅ ⺆ ⺇ ⺈ ⺉ ⺊ ⺋ ⺌ ⺍ ⺎ ⺏ ⺐ ⺑ ⺒ ⺓ ⺔ ⺕ ⺖ ⺗ ⺘ ⺙ ⺚ ⺛ ⺜ ⺝ ⺞ ⺟ ⺠ ⺡ ⺢
>   ⺣ ⺤ ⺥ ⺦ ⺧ ⺨ ⺩ ⺪ ⺫ ⺬ ⺭ ⺮ ⺯ ⺰ ⺱ ⺲ ⺳ ⺴ ⺵ ⺶ ⺷ ⺸ ⺹ ⺺ ⺻ ⺼ ⺽ ⺾ ⺿ ⻀ ⻁ ⻂ ⻃ ⻄ ⻅
>   ⻆ ⻇ ⻈ ⻉ ⻊ ⻋ ⻌ ⻍ ⻎ ⻏ ⻐ ⻑ ⻒ ⻓ ⻔ ⻕ ⻖ ⻗ ⻘ ⻙ ⻚ ⻛ ⻜ ⻝ ⻞ ⻟ ⻠ ⻡ ⻢ ⻣ ⻤ ⻥ ⻦ ⻧ ⻨
>   ⻩ ⻪ ⻫ ⻬ ⻭ ⻮ ⻯ ⻰ ⻱ ⻲ ⻳ ⼀ ⼁ ⼂ ⼃ ⼄ ⼅ ⼆ ⼇ ⼈ ⼉ ⼊ ⼋ ⼌ ⼍ ⼎ ⼏ ⼐ ⼑ ⼒ ⼓ ⼔ ⼕ ⼖ ⼗
>   ⼘ ⼙ ⼚ ⼛ ⼜ ⼝ ⼞ ⼟ ⼠ ⼡ ⼢ ⼣ ⼤ ⼥ ⼦ ⼧ ⼨ ⼩ ⼪ ⼫ ⼬ ⼭ ⼮ ⼯ ⼰ ⼱ ⼲ ⼳ ⼴ ⼵ ⼶ ⼷ ⼸ ⼹ ⼺
>   ⼻ ⼼ ⼽ ⼾ ⼿ ⽀ ⽁ ⽂ ⽃ ⽄ ⽅ ⽆ ⽇ ⽈ ⽉ ⽊ ⽋ ⽌ ⽍ ⽎ ⽏ ⽐ ⽑ ⽒ ⽓ ⽔ ⽕ ⽖ ⽗ ⽘ ⽙ ⽚ ⽛ ⽜ ⽝
>   ⽞ ⽟ ⽠ ⽡ ⽢ ⽣ ⽤ ⽥ ⽦ ⽧ ⽨ ⽩ ⽪ ⽫ ⽬ ⽭ ⽮ ⽯ ⽰ ⽱ ⽲ ⽳ ⽴ ⽵ ⽶ ⽷ ⽸ ⽹ ⽺ ⽻ ⽼ ⽽ ⽾ ⽿ ⾀
>   ⾁ ⾂ ⾃ ⾄ ⾅ ⾆ ⾇ ⾈ ⾉ ⾊ ⾋ ⾌ ⾍ ⾎ ⾏ ⾐ ⾑ ⾒ ⾓ ⾔ ⾕ ⾖ ⾗ ⾘ ⾙ ⾚ ⾛ ⾜ ⾝ ⾞ ⾟ ⾠ ⾡ ⾢ ⾣
>   ⾤ ⾥ ⾦ ⾧ ⾨ ⾩ ⾪ ⾫ ⾬ ⾭ ⾮ ⾯ ⾰ ⾱ ⾲ ⾳ ⾴ ⾵ ⾶ ⾷ ⾸ ⾹ ⾺ ⾻ ⾼ ⾽ ⾾ ⾿ ⿀ ⿁ ⿂ ⿃ ⿄ ⿅ ⿆
>   ⿇ ⿈ ⿉ ⿊ ⿋ ⿌ ⿍ ⿎ ⿏ ⿐ ⿑ ⿒ ⿓ ⿔ ⿕
>
> **Katakana and Punctuation (Half Width)**
>
> Unicode code points regex: `[\xFF5F-\xFF9F]`
>
> ｟ ｠ ｡ ｢ ｣ ､ ･ ｦ ｧ ｨ ｩ ｪ ｫ ｬ ｭ ｮ ｯ ｰ ｱ ｲ ｳ ｴ ｵ ｶ ｷ ｸ ｹ ｺ ｻ ｼ ｽ ｾ ｿ ﾀ ﾁ
>   ﾂ ﾃ ﾄ ﾅ ﾆ ﾇ ﾈ ﾉ ﾊ ﾋ ﾌ ﾍ ﾎ ﾏ ﾐ ﾑ ﾒ ﾓ ﾔ ﾕ ﾖ ﾗ ﾘ ﾙ ﾚ ﾛ ﾜ ﾝ ﾞ
>
> **Japanese Symbols and Punctuation**
>
> Unicode code points regex: `[\x3000-\x303F]`
>
> 、 。 〃 〄 々 〆 〇 〈 〉 《 》 「 」 『 』 【 】 〒 〓 〔 〕 〖 〗 〘 〙 〚 〛 〜 〝 〞 〟 〠 〡 〢 〣
>   〤 〥 〦 〧 〨 〩 〪 〫 〬 〭 〮 〯 〰 〱 〲 〳 〴 〵 〶 〷 〸 〹 〺 〻 〼 〽 〾 〿
>
> **Miscellaneous Japanese Symbols and Characters**
>
> Unicode code points regex: `[\x31F0-\x31FF\x3220-\x3243\x3280-\x337F]`
>
> ㇰ ㇱ ㇲ ㇳ ㇴ ㇵ ㇶ ㇷ ㇸ ㇹ ㇺ ㇻ ㇼ ㇽ ㇾ ㇿ ㈠ ㈡ ㈢ ㈣ ㈤ ㈥ ㈦ ㈧ ㈨ ㈩ ㈪ ㈫ ㈬ ㈭ ㈮ ㈯ ㈰ ㈱ ㈲
>   ㈳ ㈴ ㈵ ㈶ ㈷ ㈸ ㈹ ㈺ ㈻ ㈼ ㈽ ㈾ ㈿ ㉀ ㉁ ㉂ ㉃ ㊀ ㊁ ㊂ ㊃ ㊄ ㊅ ㊆ ㊇ ㊈ ㊉ ㊊ ㊋ ㊌ ㊍ ㊎ ㊏ ㊐ ㊑
>   ㊒ ㊓ ㊔ ㊕ ㊖ ㊗ ㊘ ㊙ ㊚ ㊛ ㊜ ㊝ ㊞ ㊟ ㊠ ㊡ ㊢ ㊣ ㊤ ㊥ ㊦ ㊧ ㊨ ㊩ ㊪ ㊫ ㊬ ㊭ ㊮ ㊯ ㊰ ㊱ ㊲ ㊳ ㊴
>   ㊵ ㊶ ㊷ ㊸ ㊹ ㊺ ㊻ ㊼ ㊽ ㊾ ㊿ ㋀ ㋁ ㋂ ㋃ ㋄ ㋅ ㋆ ㋇ ㋈ ㋉ ㋊ ㋋  ㋐ ㋑ ㋒ ㋓ ㋔ ㋕ ㋖ ㋗ ㋘ ㋙ ㋚ ㋛
>   ㋜ ㋝ ㋞ ㋟ ㋠ ㋡ ㋢ ㋣ ㋤ ㋥ ㋦ ㋧ ㋨ ㋩ ㋪ ㋫ ㋬ ㋭ ㋮ ㋯ ㋰ ㋱ ㋲ ㋳ ㋴ ㋵ ㋶ ㋷ ㋸ ㋹ ㋺ ㋻ ㋼ ㋽ ㋾
>   ㌀ ㌁ ㌂ ㌃ ㌄ ㌅ ㌆ ㌇ ㌈ ㌉ ㌊ ㌋ ㌌ ㌍ ㌎ ㌏ ㌐ ㌑ ㌒ ㌓ ㌔ ㌕ ㌖ ㌗ ㌘ ㌙ ㌚ ㌛ ㌜ ㌝ ㌞ ㌟ ㌠ ㌡ ㌢
>   ㌣ ㌤ ㌥ ㌦ ㌧ ㌨ ㌩ ㌪ ㌫ ㌬ ㌭ ㌮ ㌯ ㌰ ㌱ ㌲ ㌳ ㌴ ㌵ ㌶ ㌷ ㌸ ㌹ ㌺ ㌻ ㌼ ㌽ ㌾ ㌿ ㍀ ㍁ ㍂ ㍃ ㍄ ㍅
>   ㍆ ㍇ ㍈ ㍉ ㍊ ㍋ ㍌ ㍍ ㍎ ㍏ ㍐ ㍑ ㍒ ㍓ ㍔ ㍕ ㍖ ㍗ ㍘ ㍙ ㍚ ㍛ ㍜ ㍝ ㍞ ㍟ ㍠ ㍡ ㍢ ㍣ ㍤ ㍥ ㍦ ㍧ ㍨
>   ㍩ ㍪ ㍫ ㍬ ㍭ ㍮ ㍯ ㍰ ㍱ ㍲ ㍳ ㍴ ㍵ ㍶  ㍻ ㍼ ㍽ ㍾ ㍿
>
> **Alphanumeric and Punctuation (Full Width)**
>
> Unicode code points regex: `[\xFF01-\xFF5E]`
>
> ！ ＂ ＃ ＄ ％ ＆ ＇ （ ） ＊ ＋ ， － ． ／ ０ １ ２ ３ ４ ５ ６ ７ ８ ９ ： ； ＜ ＝ ＞ ？ ＠ Ａ Ｂ Ｃ
>   Ｄ Ｅ Ｆ Ｇ Ｈ Ｉ Ｊ Ｋ Ｌ Ｍ Ｎ Ｏ Ｐ Ｑ Ｒ Ｓ Ｔ Ｕ Ｖ Ｗ Ｘ Ｙ Ｚ ［ ＼ ］ ＾ ＿ ｀ ａ ｂ ｃ ｄ ｅ ｆ
>   ｇ ｈ ｉ ｊ ｋ ｌ ｍ ｎ ｏ ｐ ｑ ｒ ｓ ｔ ｕ ｖ ｗ ｘ ｙ ｚ ｛ ｜ ｝ ～

Answer (score 7):

Please see this [page](http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.unicode.shtml) for a reference. It contains Katakana, Hiragana and Kanji unicode ranges.

Comment: Answers should be self contained. Links should be for context, background material and sources. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Answer (score 1):

> What is Unicode range of all Japanese characters?

Have a look at page of [The WiLI benchmark dataset for written
language identification](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.07779.pdf#page=5), especially table II. The number in bracket is the part of the language you capture with the Unicode code range (in decimal).

- 12352 - 12543: Japanese (48.73%), English (0.00%)
- 19000 - 44000: Japanese (32.78%), English (0.00%)
- 20 - 128: English (99.74%), Japanese (11.58%)

You can see that 20 - 128 captures English really well and that all 3 blocks are important for Japanese, but still big parts are missing.

Those numbers are created with [`lidtk`](https://github.com/MartinThoma/lidtk) and [`WiLI-2018`](https://zenodo.org/record/841984).

Comment: It's surprising that 20-128 is so big. I assume most of this is using Arabic numerals and punctuation. Maybe A-Za-z when emphasising foreign words or brands.

Comment: I guess most is space, punctuation and numerals. I can check when I'm at home :-)