# how to store japanese characters into a database using python/django

Tags: python, django, web

I am creating a simple django application and I want to know how can I store and show japanese characters in this application? I'm creating the models in my django app and then this question pop up in my head.

Comment: Django tends to save things in unicode, so you [should be fine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899554/unicode-range-for-japanese)

Answer (score 0):

Doing an `ALTER` to `charset` `utf8` solved the issue:

**For Example**

```
ALTER TABLE title MODIFY 
    column VARCHAR (100)
    CHARACTER SET utf8
    COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Another Way is **cur.execute("set names utf8;")** add before query execution

```
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("set names utf8;")     # <--- add this line,
```