# How can i filter out the Japanese values in an SQL Query?

Tags: sql, oracle, unicode

I am querying from an Oracle 12c database and i need to filter out values which are in Japanese because the Java application receiving these values currently do not have the ability to display Japanese characters. For a quick demo, is there any way we can avoid the Japanese strings from the results?

Comment: by only accepting English characters ? `REGEXP_REPLACE` to replace any character which is not in English with `''`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unicode range for Japanese](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899554/unicode-range-for-japanese)

Comment: @Shnugo Not a duplicate - that just gives the unicode ranges for Japanese characters but does not show how to filter those values from a string in Oracle.

Comment: You could set NLS_LANG parameter to character set which is supported by your application. Then Oracle will replace any invalid character by ¿ automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I did not altered the NLS_LANG format to insert the Japanese character properly. Using regexp_like you can filter records which don't have alphanumeric data.

```
create table table1 (name varchar2(100));
insert into table1 (name) values ('ABC');
insert into table1 (name) values ('DEF');
insert into table1 (name) values ('GHI');
insert into table1 (name) values ('JKL');
insert into table1 (name) values ('GHI');
insert into table1 (name) values ('昨夜のコンサ');
insert into table1 (name) values ('昨夜のABC');

select * from table1;

select * from table1 where regexp_like (name,'^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$');

select nvl(regexp_replace(name,'[^0-9a-zA-Z'']',''),'blank') from table1;
```

Comment: This will simply ignore all the records, which have Japanese characters, The OP only wants to filter out the Japanese characters.

Comment: @SudiptaMondal Thanks for pointing that out. I have now edited my answer.

Comment: This will ignore too many values including punctuation and characters in languages other than Japanese. The OP's question is only about filtering out Japanese characters (and not other languages).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to replace all Non English characters with NULL for all the columns you have in your select statement.

```
select regexp_replace (column_name,'[^\x80-\xFF]',NULL) from table_name;
```

This will replace anything which is not in English characters to NULL

Comment: This will match too many characters; the OP does not want to remove non-English characters, just Japanese characters.

Comment: @MT0 wouldn't it be safe to assume, the Java application might have a restriction to only display English characters

Comment: You may assume that but that is not what the OP's question is asking.

Comment: Thanks Sudipta.. We used a similar condition to check the ascii value of the characters and anything above a certain value was filtered out,

Answer (score 0):

Given [the unicode ranges for Japanese characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19899554/1509264) you can just replace the Japanese characters:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         your_column,
         UNISTR( '[\3000-\303f\3040-\309f\30a0-\30ff\ff00-\ffef\4e00-\9faf]' ),
         NULL
       )
FROM   your_table
```

or ignore those rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  NOT REGEXP_LIKE(
         your_column,
         UNISTR( '[\3000-\303f\3040-\309f\30a0-\30ff\ff00-\ffef\4e00-\9faf]' )
       )
```