# HTML: Detect Unicode and Apply Class

Tags: html, css, unicode, lang

Is there a way to detect the unicode of the character in the html file and apply class to the nearest div/span?

For example, if there is a div containing English (Latin Characters), I want to apply 'en' class to that div. And if there is a div containing Japanese characters, I want apply 'jp' class to that div.

(if there are both then, I guess both classes can be applied).

Comment: not in pure css. You need some javascript

Comment: can you use jquery? also do you nedd only japan/english or all languges?

Comment: It is on Grails application and I am working on pdf rendering of that html file. I guess I can work with javascript but I would much prefer if its native grails functionality or at least in java/groovy.

Comment: And it would be good to scale to all languages but for now its jap and eng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `divs[i].textContent.match`

[Use unicode range](https://jrgraphix.net/research/unicode_blocks.php)

[For japanese unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899554/unicode-range-for-japanese)

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i) {
    if(divs[i].textContent.match(/[\u0020-\u007F]+/g)){
       divs[i].classList.add('eng');    
    }
    else if(divs[i].textContent.match(/[\u3041-\u3096]+/g)){
       divs[i].classList.add('jp');    
    }
}
```

```css
.eng{
color:red;
}

.jp{
color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div>english</div>
<div>良い一日を</div>
```

**EDIT**

to query for all tags in page use: `document.querySelectorAll("body *");`

```js
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll("body *");

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
        if(elements[i].textContent.match(/[\u0020-\u007F]+/g)){
           elements[i].classList.add('eng');    
        }
        else if(elements[i].textContent.match(/[\u3041-\u3096]+/g)){
           elements[i].classList.add('jp');    
        }
    }
```

```css
    .eng{
    color:red;
    }

    .jp{
    color:blue;
    }
```

```html
<div>english</div>
<div>良い一日を</div>
<span>english span</span>
<label>良い一日を</label>
```

Comment: That should do the trick for me! Although, I should extend it to query for span as well right?

Comment: Also, I should mention that your unicode seems to include only hiragana. While there is katakana (U+30A0-30FF) and kanji (U+4E00-9FBF)

Comment: about type of japanses I dont understand it as well(sorry...) (but I know to speak korean :))

Comment: Your nickname seems to be Japanese though haha

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`script` property in Unicode regexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_%28Unicode%29#List_of_scripts_in_Unicode). You can write `/^(\p{script=Han}|\p{script=Hiragana}|\p{script=Katakana})+$/` to match characters occuring in Japanese writing.