# I am trying to match Japanese characters' Unicode range, but it throws a PatternSyntaxException

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match Regex for certain Japanese characters blocks based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53807563/10385242) using the String.matches( String regex ) method in the class String.

But both the range regex `[\\x3041-\\x3096]` and the property regex `\p{Hiragana}` throw a PatternSyntaxException.
My IDE also recommends properties, but none of them Japanese characters seem to be recommended.

The code that throws this error is:

`c.matches( "[\x3041-\x3096]" )`

The StackTrace is:

```
[\x3041-\x3096]
           ^
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:2015)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.range(Pattern.java:2813)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2701)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2126)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:2056)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1778)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1427)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1068)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(Pattern.java:1173)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.matches(String.java:2024)
    at lib.UIE.TextInput.valid(TextInput.java:49)
```

Comment: Edit your question and include the exact Java source code that invokes `String.matches`.  `[\x3041-\x3096]` it is not doing what you think;  I suggest searching for `\x` in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: Are you sure that’s your code?  `"[\x3041-\x3096]"` will not compile in Java.

Comment: @VGR thanks for noticing. edited.

Answer (score 1):

For property regex try using `\p{IsHiragana}` instead. The `Is` prefix is used to distinguish unicode scripts and categories from blocks which use `In` prefix.

UPDATE For `\x3041` as @VGR mentioned \x in the original post had nothing to do with java and `\u3041` should be used instead.

```java
    Pattern.matches("\\p{IsHiragana}", "ど"); //true
    Pattern.matches("[\u3041-\u3096]", "ど"); //true
```

[Unicode support - Oracle Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/unicode.html)

Comment: Under no circumstances should a character range have a space around the hyphen.  And `\\x3041` does not represent codepoint U+3041, it represents the three ASCII characters `0`, `4`, and `1`.  (`\\x30` is U+0030, which is ASCII digit zero.)  All of this is clearly explained in [the documentation for Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: That's right, thank you! I didn't notice mistake during testing. As for the unicode for Hiragana should we use \u3041 instead?

Comment: Yes. But, as I said, there *must not* be a space before or after the `-`.

Comment: I copied from the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899554/unicode-range-for-japanese/53807563#53807563), perhaps they were incorrect with the \x?

Comment: @user10385242 The original post has nothing to do with Java and nothing to do with Java regular expressions.  `\x3400` is simply how that answer chose to denote a Unicode codepoint value.